# ASp.net core 2 Identity app sometimes looses claim when kept logged in

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I have an authorization handler, which is meant to restrict users to accessing info only for the organization they belong to, or ANY if they are of a certain account type (known as SuperAdmin here). Aforementioned account type may or may not have an associated Organization, which happens to be a navigation property. It should be mentioned I am working with "user" classes extended from ApplicationUser in the Identity framework. 
Here's the handler:

```
 public class OrganizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SameOrgRequirment, 
    Organization>
 {
     protected override Task 
       HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
       SameOrgRequirment requirement, Organization resource)
    {
        var value = context.User.FindFirst( "OrganizationID").Value;
        long claimValue = long.Parse(value);
        if(claimValue==resource.Id)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            string orgClaimValue = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == 
            "AccountTypes").Value;
            AccountTypes claimAsType = 
             (AccountTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(AccountTypes), orgClaimValue);
           if(claimAsType == AccountTypes.SuperAdmin)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }       
}
public class SameOrgRequirment:IAuthorizationRequirement{}
```

The problem is I am SOMETIMES getting a NullReferenceException on the line

```
var value = context.User.FindFirst( "OrganizationID").Value;
```

which makes no sense as all users in my dev setup have an organizationId navigation property. Inspecting the ClaimsPrincipal I see the AccountTypes claim (see below) exists but the other, OrganizationId does not when this NullReferenceException  is thrown.

I have overridden the AppClaimsPrincipalFactory to create these claims:

```
 public class AppClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>
{
    public AppClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
        , RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager
        , IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
    : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    { }

    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Type.ToString()))
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[]
            {
                new Claim("AccountTypes", user.Type.ToString())
            });
        }

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Organization.Id.ToString()))
            {
                //Used later to restrict data
                ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[]
                {
               new Claim("OrganizationId", user.Organization.Id.ToString()),
             });
            }
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[]
               {
               new Claim("OrganizationId", "-1"),
             });
        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

The AccountTypes claim doesnt seem to get lost. 
The only thing I have narrowed down is that this only seems to happen for an account where Remember Me? is checked and the app is closed and reopened via visual studio. If I log out and log back with the same account, it works fine! All claims are there and the handler works correctly. Being able to stay logged is a customer requirement so I can't really change that.